# Websocket in background on chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I have made a chrome packaged app that contains a persistent background page. The background page connects to a server via a websocket and has binding to make a notification when it receives a message.

When I first load the app and then send a message from the server I am notified as I expect. So the websocket is working. However if I wait a couple minutes(leave the app idle) and then send a message from the server the app does not respond. It seems like it is timing out(going to sleep).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this?

Comment: Same issue but in chrome on web.